# 5 PERSONAS EN UN PUENTE CON UNA LINTERNA, ALGUIEN CONOCE LA SOLUCION? 10,30,60,80,90 SEGUNDOS

Tags: matemáticas

5 personas quiereN cruzar un viejo y estrecho puente. Es una noche cerrada y se necesita llevar una linterna para cruzar, pero el grupo sólo dispone de una linterna, a la que le quedan 5 minutos de batería.Cada persona tarda en cruzar 10, 30, 60, 80 y 120 segundos, respectivamente. El puente sólo resiste un máximo de 2 personas cruzando a la vez, y cuando cruzan dos personas juntas caminan a la velocidad del más lento. No se puede lanzar la linterna de un extremo a otro del puente, así que cada vez que crucen dos personas, alguien tiene que volver a cruzar hacia atrás con la linterna a buscar a los compañeros que falten, y repetir este proceso hasta que hayan cruzado todos. ¿Cuál sería una solución válida?

No encuentro solucion que no sobrepase los 320 segundos

Comment: Hola Dina, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask], añade lo que trataste o investigaste, esta pregunta la habías realizado anteriormente https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/486948/como-puedo-resolver-este-acertijo-5-personas-y-una-linterna , evita repetir preguntas en el sitio, saludos.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

la forma en que lo haces es:

```
5 minutos es igual a 300 segundos. 
A = 10 seg
B = 30 seg
C = 60 seg
D = 80 seg
E = 120 seg

A+B cruzan, son 30 segundos (10s y 30s cruzan)
A vuelve, son 10 segundos
D+E cruzan, son 120 segundos (80s y 120s cruzan)
B vuelve, son 30 segundos, 
A y C cruzan, son 60 segundos, (10s y 60s cruzan)
A vuelve, son 10 segundos 
A y B cruzan, son 30 segundos (10s y 30s cruzan)
Total = 290 segundos
```